# Как создавать DNS записи через запрос в панель ISPManager на Python

Tags: python, dns, ispmanager

У меня есть домен, который привязан к вебхосту.
Панель управления на вебхосте: ISPManager.
Мне нужен способ, с помощью которого можно было бы отправить запрос на вебпанель и создать тем самым DNS запись. И все это нужно сделать на Python.
Как такое реализовать?

Comment: https://docs.ispsystem.ru/dnsmanager/razrabotchiku/dnsmanager-api хотяб читали?

Comment: Я читал, но не понял как все таки это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить воспользоваться библиотекой [ispmanager-python-api](https://github.com/StereoFlo/ispmanager-python-api). Ей правда четыре года, но если что, то можно форкнуть или на ее базе свою написать.

Базовый вариант по добавлению домена (от автора):

```
from isp_manager.credentials import Credentials
from isp_manager.server import Server
from isp_manager import IspManager
from isp_manager.func.domain import Add

user = Credentials('user', 'password')
server = Server('delta.hoster.net')

func = Add()
func.set_additional({
    'name': 'domain.ru',
    'ip': '127.0.0.1',
    'ns': 'dns3.domain.net. dns1.domain.net. dns2.domain.net.',
    'ns_list': '',
    'mx': 'mail',
    'mx_list': '',
    'elid': '',
    'sok': 'ok',
})

isp_manager = IspManager()
isp_manager.set_server(server)
isp_manager.set_user(user)
isp_manager.set_func(func)
print(isp_manager.execute())
```

Answer (score 0):

- Взаимодействие через API [оф. документация](https://docs.ispsystem.ru/ispmanager-lite/razrabotchiku/vzaimodejstvie-cherez-api)
- [Описание API](https://docs.ispsystem.ru/ispmanager-lite/razrabotchiku/ispmanager-api)

Думаю там найдёте, что вам нужно.

Библиотека `requests` вам в помощь (чтобы отправлять http-запросы).

Comment: Можно конкретизировать ответ (мне нужен точный ответ)? Я тоже могу написать на вопрос "Как сделать ИИ" ответить "Используй документацию Python и библиотеку Torch" :)

Comment: И первое что бы я сделал пошел бы читать доку, и понять как мне это применить. По первой ссылке даже примеры на Python есть.